# Populating array in mogo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have created the following Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Player = require('./player');

var gameSchema = new Schema({

  created_at: Date,
  nrOfCards: String,
  players: [{
          sticks: String,
          player: {
              type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: 'Player'
          }
      }],

});

var Game = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);
```

The saving part works fine and a saved object may look something like this:

```
    "_id": "57dd11aca0c36114588fd250",
    "nrOfCards": "3",
    "__v": 0,
    "players": [
      {
        "_id": "57d415e527c20f3ed2416e05",
        "age": "33"
      },
      {
        "_id": "57d417df2186d53f3d49c996",
        "age": "73"
      },
      {
        "_id": "57d41d85ec315d4234010c7d",
        "age": "20"
      }
    ]
  },
```

After having saved an object I would like to have it returned with the player-field populated. Here is my attempt:

```
   app.post('/api/games', function(req, res) {

        Game.create({
            players : req.body.activePlayers,
            nrOfCards: req.body.nrOfCards,
        }, function(err, game) {
            if (err) {
              res.send(err);
            } else {
              Game.findOne(game)
                  .populate('players.player')
                  .exec(function (err, newgame) {
                    if (err) return handleError(err);
                    console.log(newgame);
                      res.json(newgame);
                  });
            }
        });
    });
```

Thinking that the `.populate('players.player')` should do the trick , but I'm receiving the unpopulated field containing the `_id` of `player` only.

Tips appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

`player: { 
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,`
`ref: 'Player' 
}`

into your schema.